# Samsung Kies fails to restore all my stuff. What other software can I use to complete the process?

Tags: samsung-kies, restore

I spoke with the Samsung Support today, and as part of the troubleshooting process they asked me to do a backup of the phone and then reset it. I followed through and I've done that (the initial problem still remained). What they failed to tell me is that I won't be able to restore all my stuff to the phone. Because apparently, the Samsung Kies (version 2.6.1.13105_7) can only restore some parts of your data from a previous backup.

When you make a backup, it offers to include everything in the backup. Here's a list of the stuff it offers to backup.

```
 - Contacts
 - S Planner (Calendar)
 - Call log(s)
 - S Health
 - Message(s)
 - Videos
 - Music
 - Photos
 - Miscellaneous content files
 - Ringtone(s)
 - Applications
 - Home screen
 - Wi-Fi
 - Lock screen
 - Email account information
 - Other preferences
```

*(Click on screenshots below for a bigger view.)*

[image: A]
[image: B]

This is what it offers to restore after the reset.

```
 - Contacts
 - S Planner
 - Message
 - Videos
 - Music
 - Photos
 - Miscelaneous content files
```

[image: C]

Obviously, it offers to restore less than half of the things it had taken a backup of. Why offer to backup something you know you can't restore?... This makes absolutely no sense! It's absolutely insane!!

The options that I can't select for restore are greyed out. There's also a small blue warning triangle icon with exclamation mark on the side of each of these options. If I hover over this icon I get a bubble message explaining the following.

> This item cannot be restored to the connected device.

What the hell is that supposed to mean?... It's still the same bloody "smart" phone! It's not like I have switched to some Samsung Bada phone or something. It's exactly the same phone?... So what the hell!?...

**How do I restore the rest of the stuff like apps, app data, messages, account settings, customized settings, widgets and app shortcuts on the home screens?**

I can see it has taken a backup of more than it likes to admit! I can see a whole list of APK files in a subfolder of the backup location. I recognize some of them as the apps I had previously installed. So why doesn't it want to restore them then?

**File locations...**

```
Everything that has been backed up can be found in this location.

%userprofile%\Documents\samsung\Kies\Backup\GT-I9506\GT-I9506_\GT-I9506_20140108044055

Contacts, logs, messages, calendar events, etc. is stored in

.\Calllog.scl
.\Contacts.spb
.\LockScreen.sls
.\Message.sme
.\SHealth.ssh
.\SPlanner.ssc
.\Wallpaper.swp
.\WIFI.swi

Even the Wifi settings!

Apps are stored in

.\APPLICATION\_SamsungBnR_\Abackup

Some sort of settings are stored in

.\CONFIGURATION\BR\Configuration.bk

Email messages are stored in

.\EMAIL\BR\Email.bk

Music files are stored in

.\Music

App data seems to be stored in a folder named Others
e.g. the backup files from ColorNote are stored in

.\Others\data\colornote\backup

Pictures are stored in

.\Photo

Videos are stored in

.\Video
```

Photos and videos are stored as actual media files and they can be read without a problem. But all the other files (scl, spb, sls, sme, ssh, ssc, swp, swi, bk) are encoded in a format I can't read, and some might be encrypted. Is there a way I can open and make use of these files and have them imported to the phone? Or is it just garbage now?

Answer (score -1):

I solved the same problem with Samsung Kies (version 2.6.1.13105_7) installing older version 2.6.0.13074_14 downloaded from Samsung pages.

http://www.samsung.com/cz/support/model/GT-I9195ZKAETL-downloads

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution! Could you please [edit] your answer and include a link to the mentioned download page?